# Aws cdk pipeline stacks keep creating buckets on every deploy

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

Is there a way to restrict this? I'm not talking about artifact buckets, but everytime I do cdk deploy for my pipeline stack it's creating a bucket. Is there a way to limit this to a single bucket or something, does anyone know what's causing this?

My cdk stack has a codepipeline stack it creates, and every time there's a change released on the pipeline it will create another bucket, and it creates a lot of clutter very quickly. Is there any way to limit it to a single bucket?   `cdk stack code:` https://pastebin.com/XgcLNxsL

[image: buckets]

Comment: Which bucket names are you referring to?

Comment: You'd need to share some code.

Comment: @gshpychka My cdk stack pacesettercdk has a codepipeline stack that's creating those pipelinedevar buckets everytime I run a build, and it creates a lot of clutter very quickly. I've updated the question with a link to my cdk stack code, and I was wondering if there's a way to limit it to a single bucket or delete them after they've finished building or something, do you guys know why it's happening?

Comment: Did you destroy the stack between builds?

Comment: This happens when I release a change in the pipeline build, we don't need to create a stack every time that happens. One thing I'd like to note is that there's only a single deploy bucket, but every time our webhooks runs another build it creates another one of those pipelinedevar build buckets. I'd like to reduce that to a single bucket if possible, it takes a long time to delete all the clutter from the console and I don't think it's something I should focus on either